# Chemical smell in cold water supply after bathroom remodel

Tags: bathroom, pex

Last year, we had our bathroom redone after a toilet-related leak. The leak was in March and the work was finished in May. The house is from 1890 or so, and the contractors (chosen by our insurance) determined that many of the old copper pipes were rusted out and needed to be replaced. They also melted out a lead drain pipe. This is an upstairs bathroom, so they opened up the ceiling below to work on the pipes. They also put in new flooring and tiles and repainted. The new pipes are all PEX, as far as I know.

The problem is that the cold water supply lines have a horrible chemical smell and taste, almost a year later. We have tried running the water for many hours, running the water for a few minutes several times a day, etc.

- The smell is ONLY in the cold water.
- The smell is in BOTH the bathtub and the sink.
- The smell is ONLY in this bathroom. The rest of the house is fine. We are on city water, which seems to be pretty good in general.
- It seems to get a little better after running the water for a long time, but still not great. It's worst first thing in the morning after it's been sitting.
- The smell is DEFINITELY in the supply - we have filled containers of water and given them to the contractors in their office, who agreed you could smell the open container from across the room.
- The smell is NOT a sewage smell. It is a chemical smell, similar maybe to what I smelled the plumber using while he was working, maybe a lubricant or adhesive?

The contractors have not been interested in helping. They said they never heard of such a thing, and although they agree there is a smell, they will not do any work on it unless I can produce a water test that proves they did something wrong that they can fix.

Our homeowner's insurance won't cover it since it wasn't physical damage. They suggested getting the water tested as well.

We had the water tested by the city, but they can only test a limited number of things, and although the chlorine was a little high, nothing was obviously wrong from their short list of things to test. They gave us the number of a more expensive lab, but that lab told us that we would have to know what chemical to test for. I called the contractors to ask for the name of the products used by the plumber, but they never got back to me.

We have a new baby and are afraid to bathe him in water that smells and tastes so bad.

Does anyone have any ideas what could cause this smell, and what might fix it?

Comment: PEX is usually done with mechanical connections.  The only lubricant/sealer would be used at threaded connection, but they have been used forever in every house.  No smell from the toilet(tank and/or bowl) in the bathroom?

Comment: Is it in all faucets or just that one? Is there a tap close to the water source (well or city feed) and see if the smell is there too?

Comment: *name of the products used by the plumber* They'll probably never give you that. Because they have **absolutely no idea**. They probably subcontracted out the plumbing. If you're lucky, they can figure out which plumber. But even then, the plumber may have 10 guys working and nobody knows which one did that day. And if you find out which one worked that day, he probably doesn't know which chemicals he used. etc. More than about a week after the work was done (at which time any smells would likely be attributed to the equivalent of "new paint" so you wouldn't think it was a problem at the time)

Comment: it becomes virtually impossible to track this down, unless you have a specific chemical - and the testing company already told you they need to know what to look for before they will do the test. (Which reminds me of one of my favorite NSFW jokes, but I digress.)

Comment: Take this issue to your local news station.  Most have a consumer help reporter.  They may be able to get the water tested more comprehensively , and / or get some advice directly from an experienced plumbing company .

Comment: So they went back to a good spot on the old copper and interfaced that point to a new branch of all PEX? And the smell is new? Bathtub plus sink suggests that the problem is in a shared line before it branches off. Possibly even back in the old copper. Was the smell noticeable immediately after the new work was done? Or did it take a while to develop? Any noticeable trends in the long-term smell intensity?

Comment: Gasoline smell: https://www.purdue.edu/newsroom/releases/2014/Q4/drinking-water-odors,-chemicals-above-health-standards-caused-by-green-building-plumbing.html. They talk about a bunch of chemicals, so something else besides the gasoline smell chemical could be active in your case? The sustained smell has me skeptical, though. I thought a rodent could have climbed into an incomplete connection during the night and gotten sealed in there, but I would expect it to get flushed to a single outlet, with that outlet alone impacted. Sorry for mentioning the idea.

Comment: Just an idea: go to a hardware store and find a new PVC garden hose. Give it a sniff. Does it smell like the water's chemical odor? PVC hose contains a plasticizer that will give the water an awful chemical smell. I'm suggesting that the plumber used PVC hose instead of PEX for part of the repair, perhaps in a hidden area inside a wall or somewhere not readily visible. If this pans out, it's a serious offense that could put the plumber's license at risk.

Comment: Could be deposits of soldering flux, which is a mixture of various salts in a petroleum jelly matrix. When used to excess, it can give a noticeable scent to the water for a fairly long time. The only way to remove it (aside from giving it enough time) is to flush the affected pipes with either solvents or hot soapy water. You could get tricky and temporarily connect the hot water supply to the cold water piping and try to flush it out.